# How to use contains function for two dataframes

Tags: python

For example if a value from column b is in column a then print if value is present.

```py
URL_Sites_List.insert(2,'MetaData','',True)
Perform = Perform2.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
URL_Sites_List.loc[URL_Sites_List['URL'].str.contains[Perform('Banyan Hill Publishing')], 'MetaData'] = 'Banyan Hill Publishing'
```

Can I use another method for this?
if URL list contains a vlies from the dataframe perform('Banyan hill') the assign Banyan hill in the new column MetaData.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
df['c'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x['b'] if x['b'] in df['a'] else None
, axis=1)

# or as a boolean
df['c'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x['b'] in df['a']
, axis=1)
```

Comment: URL_Sites_List['MetaData'] = URL_Sites_List['URL'].apply(lamda x:'EducationDynamics' if Perform['EducationDynamics'] in URL_Sites_List['URL'] else None , axis=1)                                                          this gives an error invalid syntax on lambda x....but instead of dataframes if i put a values it works like most things ive tried i need something which will work when i use columns.   thank you though